# using smartfaces in JSF application

Tags: jsf-2

I want to use smartfaces' tags in JSF 2 application. 
Namely, I interesting in s:yUICalendar tag. 
But it is not clear for me, how do I declare it. 
Could you please show me a simple xhtml page used any smatrfaces' tag.

Answer (score 0):

Download the example of using the calendar component from their [website here](http://www.smartfaces.org/smartfaces/faces/showcase/yUICalendar.xhtml;jsessionid=9B265795B04A0D40D3F479E53FCB5F08). You need to look at the **yUICalendar.xhtml** under META-INF\resources\smartfaces\yUICalendar\